# Unexpected output on my java program

Tags: java, arraylist

My code:

```
Object tempDifference;
Object testUser;
testUser = users.get(0);
it8 = difference_time.iterator();
it9 = users.iterator();
Object tempUser;
tempDifference = difference_time.get(0);

while (it9.hasNext()) {
  tempUser = it9.next();
  System.out.println(testUser+" "+tempUser);
  if (testUser.equals(tempUser)) {
    times.add(tempDifference);
    testUser = tempUser;
  } else {
    times.add(value);
    testUser = tempUser;
  }
  tempDifference = it8.next();
}
```

- Input is: `1 2 2`
- Output is: `1 1`
- I want output `1 2`

Why is it the bad output `1 1` on beginning ?

Comment: Please use english words while posting your code on SO. It becomes difficult to differentiate between variable names. And please post all the relevant code. You haven't posted the declaration and initialization of your list you are using.

Comment: that code looks awful. clean it up please and add the missing parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most iterators start Before the first element, so the first call to next() moves them to the first element, not the second.

So, if users = {1, 2}, and boiling it down somewhat:

```
//set test = 1, the first entry in the list
test = users.get(0); 
//get a new iterator, starting before the first element
it9 = users.iterator(); 
// move to first element (the next one), so temp == 1
temp = it9.next(); 
// print values "1 1"
System.out.println(test+" "+temp);
```

Comment: What can I do to make it not be so ?

Comment: That's just how it they work...  You can just call it9.next() immediately after creating it, that will move it to the first entry, so then next call to next(), within your loop, returns the second entry in the list.